# prevent full page reload when partial fail - login register

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I create a single page to manage login and registration task in my mvc 4 app. when i create a user using registration, and registration fails - eg password mismatch - the page process the error and refresh but inserting a complete page in the renderaction part of register.

on the other hand, when login fail - user not exists - the page refresh but direct the user to a page displaying only the renderaction login part, not the whole layout.. any help appreciated:

steps: I created a model

```
public class Access
{
    public LoginModel LoginModel { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
}
```

then I create a page:

```
<div class="main-content" style="min-height: 700px;">
    <!-- Login form -->
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Login", "Account"); }

    <!-- Register form -->
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Register", "Account"); }
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

the controller is the typical one provided in mvc4 template. an example for login

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a ParitalView on fail, you may want to return the view that contains the whole page. ie
*edit*

```
//recreate the compound viewmodel in the login controller
 Access viewModel = new Access();
 viewModel.LoginModel = model;
 viewModel.RegisterModel = new RegisterModel();
return View("LoginOrRegister", viewModel); //supposing the view name is LoginOrRegister.cshtml

//recreate the compound viewmodel in the register controller
 Access viewModel = new Access();
 viewModel.LoginModel = new LoginModel();
 viewModel.RegisterModel = model;
 return View("LoginOrRegister", viewModel); //supposing the view name is LoginOrRegister.cshtml
```

also the loginorregister.cshtml page will have to use the Access class that encompasses both the LoginModel and RegisterModel as the model for the View, ie.
   @model Access

And when you render the login or register model, you need to pass in the model parameters - so that the user doesn't need to re-enter data.
*edit - Also try changing from RenderAction to Html.RenderPartial() so that it doesn't route through the actions for the intial render - do this and add [HttpPost] annotations on the controllers * the code would look something like

```
@model Access
<div class="main-content" style="min-height: 700px;">
<!-- Login form -->
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Login", new {model = Model.LoginModel, returnUrl = "?"}) };

<!-- Register form -->
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Login", "Account", new { model = Model.RegisterModel) }; }
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie:     model.RememberMe))
    {
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}

// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

//recreate the compound viewmodel in the login controller
Access viewModel = new Access();
viewModel.LoginModel = model;
viewModel.RegisterModel = new RegisterModel();
return View("LoginOrRegister", viewModel);
}
```

ah, also instead of using the viewbag to initially pass in the data, you'd have to pass it in using the model - because I've elected to use the code "@Model Acesss" in the razor view, so the register ActionResult would look like...

```
public ActionResult Register(){
    Access viewModel = new Access();
    viewModel.LoginModel = new LoginModel();
    viewModel.RegisterModel = new RegisterModel();
    return View("LoginOrRegister",viewModel);
}
```

I didn't realize you were so new to mvc. Keep at it. :) Another tutorial may help

Comment: thanks, everything seems to be correct. but I receive the following error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'LoginModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Access'. return View("LoginOrRegister", model); must be inserted in loginorregister or in login and in register controller?. thanks!

Comment: 'return View("LoginOrRegister", model)' would have to be inserted into both. ahh. I made a mistake in that you're going to have to re-create an access viewmodel. I'll edit the answer, hang on

Comment: ah, I didn't really think about that you're using renderaction, hmm, still need to think. you may want to seperate out the postback and the non postback calls?

Comment: im following this information founded based on your implementation http://mvc4beginner.com/Sample-Code/Authentication-Authorization/ASP-.NET-MVC-SignOn-Register-In-The-Same-Form.html

Comment: right, make sure to use RenderPartial instead of RenderAction

Comment: RenderPartial routes it to the .cshtml razor view. RenderAction routes it back through the controller. In this case you don't want it to route through your controller untill its a postback.

Comment: also, although the tutorial use a viewbag to pass the data the view, I would use your compound view model (the access class)

Comment: also, I'd recommend a different tutorial. that one isn't so great. good luck